# How to configure chef rbenv and ruby-build cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra, rhel, rbenv, knife, knife-solo

Although no errors are thrown upon initial deploy using this run-list:

`"run_list": [ "recipe[ruby_build]", "recipe[rbenv::system_install]", "recipe[main]" ]`

... subsequent deploys throw multiple rsync errors like:

`rsync: delete_file: unlink(ruby-build/share/ruby-build/1.9.3-p392) failed: Permission denied (13)`

It seems the permissions of `/tmp/chef-solo` are set to root.

What's the right way to configure the [rbenv](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv) and [ruby-build](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-ruby_build) cookbooks using knife-solo?

EDIT:

This question is really just about how to properly configure and use these two cookbooks, for example to do a [user_install](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv#-user_install).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was using outdated cookbook versions. And I didn't really know how the run list worked.

To install rbenv and ruby_build via their respective cookbooks, see the following file configuration...

**Cheffile**:

```rb
site 'http://community.opscode.com/api/v1'
cookbook 'rbenv', :git => 'https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv', :ref => 'master' 
cookbook 'ruby_build', :git => 'https://github.com/fnichol/chef-ruby_build', :ref => 'master'
```

make sure to `librarian-chef install` after updating the Cheffile

**site-cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb**:

```rb
depends 'ruby_build'
depends 'rbenv'
```

**nodes/dna.json**:

```js
{
  "rbenv": {
    "rubies":["1.9.3-p484"],
    "global":"1.9.3-p484",
    "gems":{
      "1.9.3-p484":[
        {"name": "bundler"},
        {"name":"rails", "version": "4.0.2"},
        {"name": "rake", "version": "10.1.1"}
      ]
    }
  },
  "run_list":[
    "ruby_build", // required by "rbenv::system"
    "rbenv::system", // installs rubies and gems from dna, takes a while to finish the first time; see configuration options at https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv#attributes
    "my_cookbook::default"
  ]
}
```

Setting these configuration variables in a recipe using `node.default["var_name"] = "value_name"` as suggested by the [cookbook docs](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv#attributes), did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `chef-client` as root.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade knife-solo. The [issue](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo/issues/86) was fixed back in v0.3.0. You might want to read the [upgrade instructions](https://github.com/matschaffer/knife-solo/wiki/Upgrading-to-0.3.0) while at it.

Comment: since there is no longer a /tmp/chef directory, which directory should be referenced in the following example? `content IO.read("/tmp/chef-solo/site-cookbooks/main/files/SOME_PATH_TO_FILE")`

Comment: The default upload is `~/chef-solo`, but you can override it with config option `knife[:provisioning_path]` or using CLI option `--provisioning-path`. Reading them directly in your cookbooks sounds like an anti-pattern. Why don't you use `cookbook_file` resource?

Comment: after revisiting the [ cookbook_file documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_cookbook_file.html), i realize i had been reversing the `source` and `path` attributes. now i'm using the cookbook_file resource for this purpose. thanks!